# Cloned NVMe drive not being recognized as a bootable drive on an Asus Q525U laptop

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, clone

I have an Asus Q525U laptop with Windows 10. It originally came with a hard disk drive, but has an empty slot for an NVMe SSD, which I wanted to use to increase system performance.

I opened the system and installed the SSD, and it was recognized just fine. I then booted into Clonezilla to clone the HDD to the SSD. The new SSD is smaller, and it initially wouldn't let me clone, but I used an option to force it anyway. (I had previously shrunk the partition to fit within the smaller drive.)

However, after the cloning operation was complete, the UEFI would not recognize the SSD as bootable. Worse, when booting off the original hard drive, the system just chugs and runs extremely slowly compared to before (basic tasks like opening a new browser tab take a couple minutes).

I tried resetting the BIOS settings to default, and that partially resolved the extreme slowness issue (I had disabled Secure Boot and enabled CSM to start Clonezilla).

How can I get the system to recognize the new SSD as bootable?

I think a possible solution is to boot the system using a portable Windows To Go drive and use Macrium Reflect to do the clone, as I've had success with that before with UEFI setups. Will that work?

Comment: Macrium Reflect doesn't use "Windows To Go" it uses WinPE.  "Windows To Go" is a portable installation of media, which Microsoft does not support, due to the fact it's extremely slow no matter what type of USB mass storage your using.  **WinPE is fully supported**